# Invalid Workflow File

Tags: github, pipeline, github-actions

I get error: "a step cannot have both the `uses` and `run` keys", but I don't see that one step have both `uses` and `run`. Can someone help me figure it out what is wrong with this?

```
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
    - master

env:
  IMAGE_NAME: api

jobs:
  build:
    name: Application build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout repository (#1)
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: 3.1.101
    - name: Build API
      run: dotnet build --configuration Release

  tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout repository (#2)
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: 3.1.101
    - name: Run API Tests
      run: dotnet test

  auto-approve:
    name: Auto approve pull request
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: hmarr/auto-approve-action@v2.0.0
      with:
        github-token: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"

  automerge:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: automerge
      uses: "pascalgn/automerge-action@ccae530ae13b6af67a7a2009c266fe925844e658"
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"

  docker-build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Build the Docker image
      run: docker build . --file Dockerfile --tag my-image-name:$(date +%s)

  docker-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Push Docker image to registry
      uses: jerray/publish-docker-action@master
      with:
        username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
        registry: docker.pkg.github.com
        repository: jerray/publish-docker-action
        auto_tag: true
```

Comment: I have just copied your code and at least I didn't get the error. can you try to create a pull request again?

Comment: I'm getting the same error! It's wired, I copied the GitHub example and it's giving me this error! Maybe some space or lining issue as YAML files are very sensitive to that!